# ASP.Net framework for data read application and report generation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, architecture, webformsmvp

I was looking for a best framework to develop an ASP.Net Web application.
   It will be using database MS SQL Server 2000 (It has to deal with other application)
   The Web server is equipped with .Net 4.0 framework

The application is mainly reading data and displaying to the user. Writing to the database is very seldome. And it should have an option to generate reports also.

Which architecture solution I should choose develop such an application?

What will be best approach?

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net Webform would be easier especially if you need render report in a gridview, it also enable you to drag and drop lots of controls for fast development. You can write minimum code to achieve reading data and displaying to the user, such as defining datasource in aspx page of a gridview.

MVC on the other hand requires you to write every bit of Html by yourself, though there are some auto generated razer views, you gain more controls and get rid of viewstate, but it takes much more time to develop and learn.

You should use EF regardless which architecture you choose, it's an ORM tool for writting multi-layered applications